# c ++ Win32 API Как менять цвета только у своего приложения, подобно SetSysColors?

Tags: c++

Пишу приложения на C++, использую функции Win32 API.  Функция SetSysColors замечательно меняет раскраску, но влияет на цвета всех приложений OS Windows. Как менять цвета только у своего приложения ?

Comment: Нарисовать своё окно?

Answer (score 1):

Способ 1:

- В нужном вам месте создаете кисть, используя функцию `CreateSolidBrush`
  и вызовом функции `InvalidateRect` перерисовываете окно;
- В оконной функции обрабатываете сообщение `WM_PAINT` и заливаете окно
  ранее созданной кистью, используя для этого функцию `FillRect`.

Способ 2, подходит для диалоговых окон:

- В нужном вам месте создаете кисть, используя функцию `CreateSolidBrush`
  и вызовом функции `InvalidateRect` перерисовываете окно;
- В оконной функции обрабатываете сообщение `WM_CTLCOLORDLG`и просто
  возвращаете созданную ранее кисть: `return (INT_PTR)hBrush`.